# Jar created with manifest not finding classes

Tags: java, jar, ant, manifest

I have created a jar due ant that has the following manifest.mf

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.9.14
Created-By: 1.7.0_80-b15 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: eu.ohim.ebc.filenet.app.StartApplication
Class-Path: dist/DocExtract.jar ./lib/ErrorControl_2.1.jar
```

Jar has the following content

```
--> META-INF 
  --> MANIFEST.MF 

--> eu
  --> ohim
    --> ebc
      --> filenet
        --> app
          --> StartApplication.class
```

At the same level as dist, I have a folder called lib with ErrorControl_2.1.jar.

So, the structure is

```
build.xml
dist
  --> DocExtract.jar
lib
  --> ErrorControl_2.1.jar
```

If I try to do a java ant target from the base directory, I receive a classNotFoundException for a class inside ErrorControl_2.1.jar . Looks like is not finding the jar . Do I have to attach inside the jar generated all the jar files , and , in manifest, use the path inside the jar ? Is this path relative to the jar, or relative to the place I'm executing java -jar ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok . It's solved . There's no need to add external jar inside the jar I'm executing . And , inside the manifest.mf, the paths must be relative to the jar that wrapps this manifest.